# Split a network according to a vector of nodes

Tags: network, road, splitting, nodes

I would like to split a network of roads at the vertices just created in another layer. So, I have got a roads layer and a nodes layer and I would like to exploit the nodes layer in order to obtain a graph from the roads made by edges defined by those nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Esri Split tool. Here you can add your line layer as in features and points layer as split features. Lines would split at nodes location.

. For more information click [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm) and [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/ways-to-split-a-line-feature.htm)

Comment: Do you have any open source solution in your mind ? For example any way of doing it in QGIS or any other open source software ?